# SQL JOIN and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

What is wrong with my query?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table1
JOIN 
    table2 
ON 
    table2.table1_id = table1.id
WHERE 
    table_2.table3_id = 1 
ORDER BY 
    table2.id 
ASC
```

It does what I want except it doesn't consider my ORDER BY and apparently keeps ordering by table1.id ASC by default instead of table2.id ASC.

It's like my ORDER BY just doesn't exist.

Note that there is a space between the closing quote and the ORDER BY (otherwise I would get an error message anyway, which I don't).

Comment: That's not valid SQL.  What language is that?  Can you provide just the SQL piece?

Comment: The ".$_GET['table3_id']." part is just an imported variable from PHP.
It's not an issue here since the value is well imported and no message error is thrown.
So, just consider that ".$_GET['table3_id']." is any value.
It's consistent with the result, whatever value I enter as I get the correct output. But just order by table1.id instead of table2.id
I edited the script so that it's not confusing and PHP is out of the way. Hope it helps

Comment: It's **very much** an issue, since it leaves you wide open to a **HUGE GAPING SECURITY VULNERABILITY**. It would be trivial, for example, to use that field to erase your entire database or steal data from your users.

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with the query as shown. What have you tried for debugging, eg selecting just `table2.id` instead of `*` - presumably this is an integer column and not a string.

Comment: Ok, got it, it should be sanitized first. Bt now I'm not in production, I'm just trying a query and play with it on my own. Of course, when the query works, I sanitize my input variable between the "GET" and the database so that no one can mess with the query.
I edited the script.

Comment: No. Sanitizing is the _wrong approach_. You need to use parameterized queries/prepared statements, which _do not sanitize the inputs_. Rather, this technique **quarantines** the inputs. it isolates them away from the rest of the query, so they are never at any point used in the same string. This is one of those things that's too important to do wrong at any level... even for learning and proof of concept projects.

Comment: Ok. I got the point and will look at it, thanks.
By the way, I changed the "*" with "table2.id" and it worked.
Why is "*" not...everything (table2_id included) then ?

Comment: Ok I got the answer below. it should be " table2.* ". Thanks. Ans I will definitely look right now at the parameterized queries/prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your query is that in the ORDER BY clause, you are specifying "table2.id" but the query result doesn't have a column named "table2.id", it only has "table1.id" and "table2.id".

You can change your query to:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT 
            table1.*, 
            table2.* 
         FROM 
            table1
         JOIN 
            table2 
         ON 
            table2.table1_id = table1.id
         WHERE 
            table_2.table3_id =".$_GET['table3_id']." 
         ORDER BY 
            table2.id 
         ASC";
```

This way you are selecting both the columns from table1 and table2 and it will order the result set by table2.id

Alternatively, you can also use an alias for table2 and use that alias in the ORDER BY clause like:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT 
            table1.*, 
            table2.* 
         FROM 
            table1
         JOIN 
            table2 
         ON 
            table2.table1_id = table1.id
         WHERE 
            table_2.table3_id =".$_GET['table3_id']." 
         ORDER BY 
            table2.id 
         ASC";
```

This way you can use the alias in the ORDER BY clause

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Your second script is identical to the first one though.

Comment: How is `select * from table1 join table2 on table2.table1_id = table1.id` different from `select table1.*, table2.* from table1 join table2 on table2.table1_id = table1.id`?  In SQL Server, they would return identical results.  So as far as I can tell, table2.id is in the output.  But that's not relevant.  The results should be ordered by table2.id even if it is not in the results.  Do we know which RDBMS the OP is using?